# Decimal to binary using Bitwise operator

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int decimal_num, c, result;

  printf("Enter an integer in decimal number system\n");
  scanf("%d", &decimal_num);

  for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
  {
    result = decimal_num >> c;

    if (result & 1)
      printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
  }

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

This code takes a decimal number and converts it into binary using bitwise operator. I am having a hard time understanding the logic inside the for loop `result = decimal_num >> c` and why does it iterate from `for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)`. I understand the basics of bitwise AND, OR, XOR and NOT and I know that when an odd number is ANDED with '1' the result is '1' else '0'(because the least significant bit of all odds are 1).

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code line by line. And read more about the *shift* operators.

Comment: 0-31: 32 iterations, that should be related to the bit size of ints on that machine. `decimal_num>>c` + `result&1` looks like something to isolate and examine a single bit... Read about shifting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an explanation of the code :

The program scans the bitwise representation of the decimal digit from left to write, working on each bit. The decimal digit is supposed to have 32 bits, hence the for loop runs 32 times.

The first time, the value of c is 31.

Assuming the bit representation of decimal_num initially is
x................................  ( . represents any digit )

decimal_num >> 31 shifts all bits rightwards 31 times, such that the first bit is shifted at the right most end. The result is 0000000000000000000000000000x. Note that when digits are shifted, 0 is pre-pended to the left end.

The result is then checked to see if it was 0 or 1, and printed accordingly.
0000000000000000000000000000x & 00000000000000000000000000001 = 1 if x is one
0000000000000000000000000000x & 00000000000000000000000000001 = 0 if x is zero.

Moving on, and checking the second bit when c is 30. :

.Y..............................

decimal_num >> 30 results in
000000000000000000000000000000.Y

000000000000000000000000000.Y & 00000000000000000000000000001 = 1 if Y is one
000000000000000000000000000.Y & 00000000000000000000000000001 = 0 if Y is zero.

We go on printing the results until the last digit.

Hope this helps you understand.